# How to use Box Sizing

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am currently working on a personal website. What I want to accomplish is something like this... http://gyazo.com/741e08b227cb1e65f985bdd6b707815c
However as I am a complete newbie to html, css, and js, I have no clue how to code this out.

What I currently have is this...

```
HTML
<section id="app">
    <div>
        <h2>app</h2>
        <p>This is sample description <br> for an iOS application.</p>
        <img src="appicon.png">
    <div>
</section>

CSS
#app {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
background-color: #28D9F9;}
```

This website http://www.nothingmagical.com has a very similar layout that I want to achieve. From poking through codes, I understand that he is using "box-sizing" to achieve vertical and horizontal alignment. If anybody can help me code this out, that will be great. Cheers!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, but `box-sizing` has very little to do with alignment.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Please elaborate more or add a fiddle.

Comment: If you're new to html/css I would recommend reading tutorials and then getting an overview over all the different layout types (inline vs. block, floating, positioning, flexboxes) etc. instead of asking for one feature at a time. You could also search stackoverflow for similar questions, basics probably have already been covered.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: for someone that uses viewport height  and viewport width I am very suprised that you don't know what box-sizing is, the 2 links are probably more of a reason to ask the question than box sizing

Answer (score -1):

Read this to know more about box-sizing:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Wow, I got down voted for teaching someone what box-sizing really is...